# data.table get N most frequent values by group

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I want to find, for each purchase category, the top 3 most frequently occurring zip codes.  In this example, the categories are *home*, *townhouse*, and *condo*.  I have transactional data like:

```
set.seed(1234)
d <- data.table(purch_id = 1:3e6,
                purch_cat = sample(x = c('home','townhouse','condo'), 
                                   size = 3e6, replace=TRUE),
                purch_zip = formatC( sample(x = 1e4:9e4, size = 3e6, replace=TRUE), 
                                     width = 5, format = "d", flag = "0") )
```

I know that I can do this:

```
# there has to be a better way...
d[,list(purch_count = length(purch_id)), 
  by=list(purch_cat, purch_zip)][, purch_rank := rank(-purch_count, ties.method='min'), 
                                 by=purch_cat][purch_rank<=3,][order(purch_cat, purch_rank)]

    purch_cat purch_zip purch_count purch_rank
 1:     condo     39169          32          1
 2:     condo     15725          31          2
 3:     condo     75768          30          3
 4:     condo     72023          30          3
 5:      home     71294          30          1
 6:      home     56053          30          1
 7:      home     57971          29          3
 8:      home     77521          29          3
 9:      home     70124          29          3
10:      home     25302          29          3
11:      home     65292          29          3
12:      home     39488          29          3
13: townhouse     39587          33          1
14: townhouse     80365          30          2
15: townhouse     37360          30          2
```

But this can't be the most elegant `data.table` approach, and it seems kind of slow.

Any suggestions to reduce the number of passes?  Maybe something using `table()`? TYVM!

Comment: @Frank that seems right actually, for real world use... if there are ties

Comment: @Frank it's just the tie-breaking logic, but it's not that big of a deal.  I just wanted purch_rank <= 3 to ensure that I got at least three results.  I could get five zips tied for first (and then the next one would be rank six), etc.  I'm open to a variety of tie handling rules.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 actually, see edit. your answer was basically correct.

Comment: `frank()` will also be internally optimised [to avoid the `eval()` penalty] in the next version (hopefully)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Edit: improved.

I think you were exactly on the right track. One key thing you're missing, however, is the function `frank`, which has been optimized and should speed up your code considerably (runs almost instantaneously on your 3m row sample data):

```
d[ , .(purch_count = .N), 
  by = .(purch_cat, purch_zip)
  ][, purch_rank := frank(-purch_count, ties.method = 'min'), 
    keyby = purch_cat
    ][purch_rank <= 3,
      ][order(purch_cat, purch_rank)]
    purch_cat purch_zip purch_count purch_rank
 1:     condo     39169          32          1
 2:     condo     15725          31          2
 3:     condo     75768          30          3
 4:     condo     72023          30          3
 5:      home     71294          30          1
 6:      home     56053          30          1
 7:      home     57971          29          3
 8:      home     77521          29          3
 9:      home     70124          29          3
10:      home     25302          29          3
11:      home     65292          29          3
12:      home     39488          29          3
13: townhouse     39587          33          1
14: townhouse     80365          30          2
15: townhouse     37360          30          2
```

---

## Incomplete answer with `table` (slow):

Yes, one way involves using `table`.

```
d[ , {x <- table(purch_zip)
x <- x[order(-x)]
names(x[x %in% unique(x)[1:3]])
}, keyby = purch_cat]
    purch_cat    V1
 1:     condo 39169
 2:     condo 15725
 3:     condo 72023
 4:     condo 75768
 5:      home 56053
 6:      home 71294
 7:      home 25302
 8:      home 39488
 9:      home 57971
10:      home 65292
11:      home 70124
12:      home 77521
13:      home 16943
14:      home 43003
15:      home 43426
16:      home 76501
17:      home 81754
18:      home 88978
19: townhouse 39587
20: townhouse 37360
21: townhouse 80365
22: townhouse 22402
23: townhouse 33518
24: townhouse 59347
25: townhouse 83099
    purch_cat    V1
```

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 you could probably speed it up a tiny bit more by limiting the number of ties, and subsetting in the second step before calculating `frank` on _all_ of the zips, which is expensive if there are a lot of zips which will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks very much for this (+1).  On data.table 1.9.5, @Frank's is slightly faster (.330 vs .370 sec, vs. OP .500 on my laptop), posted first, and possibly less clunky, but yours taught me a new function, so I am accepting this one.

Answer (score 7):

One approach would be

```
d[ , .N, by=.(purch_cat, purch_zip)][
  order(-N), 
  .SD[ N >= unique(N)[3] ]
,by=purch_cat]
```

which gives

```
    purch_cat purch_zip  N
 1: townhouse     39587 33
 2: townhouse     80365 30
 3: townhouse     37360 30
 4: townhouse     83099 28
 5: townhouse     33518 28
 6: townhouse     59347 28
 7: townhouse     22402 28
 8:     condo     39169 32
 9:     condo     15725 31
10:     condo     75768 30
11:     condo     72023 30
12:      home     71294 30
13:      home     56053 30
14:      home     57971 29
15:      home     77521 29
16:      home     70124 29
17:      home     25302 29
18:      home     65292 29
19:      home     39488 29
20:      home     81754 28
21:      home     43426 28
22:      home     16943 28
23:      home     88978 28
24:      home     43003 28
25:      home     76501 28
    purch_cat purch_zip  N
```

---

To achieve the OP's tie-breaking rule, one could do

```
d[ , .N, by=.(purch_cat,purch_zip)][
  order(-N),
  .SD[ N >= unique(N)[3] ][
      .N - frank(N, ties.method='max') < 3 ]
, by=purch_cat]
```

which gives

```
    purch_cat purch_zip  N
 1: townhouse     39587 33
 2: townhouse     80365 30
 3: townhouse     37360 30
 4:     condo     39169 32
 5:     condo     15725 31
 6:     condo     75768 30
 7:     condo     72023 30
 8:      home     71294 30
 9:      home     56053 30
10:      home     57971 29
11:      home     77521 29
12:      home     70124 29
13:      home     25302 29
14:      home     65292 29
15:      home     39488 29
```

Following @MichaelChirico's answer, this approach adds an `frank` step.

Comment: Thanks again Frank -- incidentally this appears to be the the fastest solution among the three.  According to my benchmark, OP = .555 sec, yours was .370, @MichaelChirico's was 3.5 sec.  *wait -- looking at his update*

Comment: I understand the reason for `N >= unique(N)[3]`, but I guess my thinking is that if there was a five-way tie for first, I wouldn't need to see the sixth zip code (and its ties, and then the one after that, and its ties).  I know I said that I'm open to a variety of tie-breaking methods, but I feel like if there were a lot of ties the other approach would be closer to what I was looking for.  Thanks again, I learned a lot from this (+1)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Thanks. I get where you're coming from and will update the answer and let you know if I find a way (as I would also be interested in doing that); I just haven't had time to take a look yet.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Updated. Turns out that it can be written in the same way with one extra step.